# decryption in asm

Tags: assembly

In ASM i have the following code which encrypts a character.

Inputs:

- EAX = Encryption Key value
- ECX = the character to be encrypted

Outputs:

- EAX = the encrypted value of the source character

Code:

```
encrypt11: push edx  
           push ecx  
           ror al,1
           ror al,1   
           ror al,1   
           mov edx,eax     
           pop eax     
           sub eax,0x02   
           xor eax,edx   
           rol al,1       
           rol al,1   
           rol al,1   
           pop edx     
           ret
```

I am stuck on an assignment in which i need to "reverse" this so that i can get the original string that has been 'encrypted'... Im sorry to ask guys but so far ive changed the ROL's to ROR's and vice versa.. The sub has been changed to add but i am still lost. Can anyone shed any light on this? whilst sticking to the original code as much as possible without missing anything?

Comment: @jacklikesnike: you should include which registers contain what data. They syntax looks like Intel instead of AT&T, so that part is clear. But what's in ECX, EDX and EAX? In fact ECX is used in one place only.

Comment: Im really not sure how to find out whats in ECX and EDX and EAX.. im seriously struggling with tihs :( sorry guys

Comment: @jacklikesnike: well, can you tell us whether a "character" in that assignment can be assumed to be 8 bit? Side-note: the contents of EDX before the function (assuming this is a complete function) don't matter.

Comment: In the assignment i have to input the character "Y" as the encryption key yes.."// Skeletal Encrypt subroutine. You should paste in the encryption routine you've been allocated from BB and
// overwrite this initial version. Leave on the appended number but change the ‘call’ above to use the
// correct 'encryptnn' label where nn is your encryption routine number.
// Inputs: register EAX = Encryption Key value, and ECX = the character to be encrypted.
// Outputs: register EAX = the encrypted value of the source character."

Comment: That was vital information. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for replying though mate i appreciate it.

Comment: yeah, gimme a moment I'm now looking at the code, doesn't look too hard

Comment: @jacklikesnike: one more question. The encryption key is also the decryption key?

Comment: i would have thought so yes :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, give this a try and please ask the questions you have and I'll amend my answer accordingly:

```
; EAX: en/decryption key
; ECX: plain character
encrypt11:
    push edx     ; simply save edx
    push ecx
    ror al,1     ; modify key
    ror al,1
    ror al,1
    mov edx,eax  ; edx = <modified key>
    pop eax      ; eax = <original character>
    sub eax,0x02 ; eax -= 2
    xor eax,edx  ; eax ^= edx
    rol al,1     ; modify encrypted character
    rol al,1
    rol al,1
    pop edx ; simply restore edx
    ret

; EAX: en/decryption key
; ECX: encrypted character
decrypt11:
    push edx     ; simply save edx
    push ecx
    ror al,1     ; modify key
    ror al,1
    ror al,1
    mov edx,eax  ; edx = <modified key>
    pop eax      ; eax = <encrypted character>
    ror al,1     ; modify encrypted character
    ror al,1
    ror al,1
    xor eax,edx  ; eax ^= edx
    add eax,0x02 ; eax += 2
    pop edx
    ret
```

Let's take the following names `key` and `chr` for the input to encryption. The gist is that in the encryption the first thing done is to modify (the three `ror`) the `key`, which yields `key'`. Then we subtract from the input character 2, which yields `chr'`. Then `chr'` and `key'` are being combined with `xor`, yielding `chr''`. Once that is done `chr''` is modified further (the three `rol`), yielding the output value `echr`.

For decryption we input `echr` and `key` again. Then we need to get `chr''` from `chr` (the three `ror` in decryption). Then we need to get `key'` from `key` and xor-combine `key'` and `chr''`, yielding `chr'`. From there we only add 2 to `chr'` to yield `chr` as output.

Comment: Unfortunately not.. this isnt outputting my original string i put in. I input 'Y' then i input a 5 letter word. for example 'Lemon'.. and i dont get the original string back.

Comment: I'm sorry, that makes no sense. The explanation from your side about the input was: one character in one character out. Try it on one character then. We have no clue what other code there is ;)

Comment: It wont let me copy any of the rest of the code in sadly :( http://rapidshare.com/files/456611226/New.cpp this is the code. Thanks alot mate

Comment: I don't know who wrote the code, but the decryption routine takes the *original* characters and 'decrypts' these, which of course yields the wrong results.

Comment: And, surprise surprise, my code was absolutely correct. Inside `decrypt_chars` you need to read from `EChars`, *not* from `OChars` (as in `encrypt_chars`).

Comment: honestly mate. i would marry you if i could. Thanks a million

Comment: @jacklikesnike: upvoting and accepting the answer would be enough, as far as I'm concerned ;)